# Installing hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, homebrew, linuxbrew

I'm using ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) and trying to install hadoop using brew.But I'm experiencing this error.

```
brew install hadoop
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz
Error: Failed to download resource "hadoop"
Download failed: Couldn't determine mirror, try again later.
```

Is this a server error or the command '`brew install hadoop`' needs correction ?

Comment: Why don't you just download the tar ball and untar?

Comment: Brew is a package manager for OS X.

Comment: @Chiron He is probably talking about linuxbrew: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew

Answer (score 2):

Your command

```
brew install hadoop
```

has worked for me in the past: it should work for you.  Maybe try following exactly what the message says: "try again".

Answer (score 0):

The location (url)

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz

Points to a list of mirror sites.

1) Pick one (a Mirror) and use that url; for me that would be

http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz

I'd also check your location/locale setting with the following command

```
locale
```

Brew does not ask for the locale to be set in the setup, so I assume its picked up from your locale settings..

Ref https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/wiki/Standalone-Installation

Hope this helps